# How to compare azure resources configuration

Tags: c#, .net, azure, cloud

I have two resources of the same kind and want to find a easy way to compare their configuration to find differences.

In my project I have several resources of the same kind but with slightly different configuration. I want to make a list of the configuration differences and want to find a easy way to do so.

I'm quite new to azure but I know there is a Resource explorer who shows me configuration in JSON format, but I'm not sure if this shows me the whole configuration or just a part of it and I don't know how to access it / download this configuration via CLI for comparison.

The resources are of different kind e.g. comsos db, key vault, data lake etc.

Whats the best way to do this task?

Comment: Which resources? You need to provide more details.

Comment: @JoyWang the resources are of different kind e.g. cosmos db, key vault, data lake etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I know, the Azure Storage Explorer will inculde the whole(or close to whole, this depends on specific case) configuration.

If you want to use CLI, you could use this command - [`az resource show`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/resource?view=azure-cli-latest#az-resource-show), it shows the details of the resources, just specify the `--resource-type` with what resource you want.

```
az resource show [--api-version]
                 [--ids]
                 [--include-response-body {false, true}]
                 [--name]
                 [--namespace]
                 [--parent]
                 [--resource-group]
                 [--resource-type]
                 [--subscription]
```

Comment: Cool, thanks! Didn't know it was that easy and wasn't sure all configuration is shown there.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in another answer the azure CLI can help you - but it does not always show the whole picture!

One in a while you will find some configuration that is not expressed in the `show` subcommand (I know I saw this a couple of times but I can't recall concrete examples, so take this with a grain of salt).

Another thing to be aware of (but that wou can work around) is when you have subordinate ARM objects, like for CDN where you have the CDN profile and then it's endpoints, which are separate ARM objects. Or more complex, cases like Databricks where you have a very simple object that spawn it's own infrastructure in a separate resource group.

But in general, using AzCLI with the `show` subcommand can help quite a bit.